# Is there a way to predict the value of an uninitialized variable?

Tags: c, memory

Is there a way to predict the value of an uninitialized variable in C language?

For example:

```
int i;
if ( i == <a number in the memory> ) 
{
    //task;
}
```

And what if we use pointers?

```
int* p;
if ( p == NULL ) // or a number again
{
    //task;
}
```

Comment: If there were a way, wouldn't it mean that a program with uninitialized variables is well-defined? But, it is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) to use uninitialized variables. If you do rely on such behavior then your program would be non-conformant. Here's the quote from the documentation of [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior): _"Note: [Strictly conforming](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conformance) programs do not depend on any unspecified, undefined, or implementation-defined behavior"_.

Comment: @Azeem: That meaning of “non-conformant” is not very useful as very few practical programs are strictly conforming. Programs cannot use Internet connections, draw graphics on displays, link to libraries not written in C, call operating system functions, or do many other useful things without being “non-conformant” in that sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do not initialize an object, the C standard does not say what its value will be, or even that it will hold a fixed value or that, depending on other factors, the program will have any defined behavior.

Nonetheless, when you compile and execute a program, it executes on a physical machine that operates mechanically according to rules, and therefore there is at least some predictability. To some degree, you can sometimes predict the value of an object by examining the assembly code generated by the compiler and reading the documentation for the developer tools, the operating system, and the processor you are using. This is usually not a productive course of action just to figure out what value some uninitialized object may have, although sometimes it can be useful in debugging.

Note that the C standard says that when an object is not initialized, its value is *indeterminate*. This not only means the value is not determined by rules of the C standard but that the object may behave as if it does not have a fixed value at all—its apparent value may vary each time it is used. In effect, partially, the C standard says to the compiler “If the program does not initialize an object, then, when its value is used, you do not have to bother loading it from memory. It is okay if you just use whatever value is in the register you would have loaded it to, even if that register has been used for some other purpose since the last time you did this.”

Comment: Thank you for the  detailed answer. Appreciate it.

Comment: Nice answer.  (To the OP): In particular, as to the second paragraph, one could emphasize that this means the contents of uninitialized variables are not suitable for use in generating random numbers (even if you could rely on the program being able to access their values, which you can't).  For security purposes, it also means that if you have a buggy program that uses uninitialized variables, an attacker might be able to predict their values, or even set them to values of his choosing, and so you should assume this is possible unless you can prove otherwise.